# Questions about giving an example in subspace topology exercise

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, separable-spaces

I just want to know if my guess for the following question is correct"

> Give an example of a separable Hausdorff space $(X,T)$ that has a subspace $(A, T_{A})$ is not separable.

I am guessing $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $A=\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2):

A space $A$ is separable iff $A$ has a countable dense subset $D$. If $A$ is countable we may take $D=A.$ So any countable space is separable.

Properly speaking, a topological space is a pair $(X,T_X)$ where $T_X$ is a topology on $X.$ And if $A\subseteq X,$ then the subspace topology on $A$ (with respect to the topology $T_X$) is $\{t\cap A: t\in T_X\}.$

It  is very common (& accepted) to speak of a space $X$ when what is meant is a space $(X,T_X),$ where the nature of $T_X$  may (or maybe not!) be understood from the context. Also  common (& accepted) is to speak of a subspace $A$ of $X ,$ which  is an abbreviation for  (i) $A\subseteq X,$ and (ii) $T_X$ is some topology on $X,$ and  (iii) the topology chosen for  $A$ is $\{t\cap A: t\in T_X\}.$   The abbreviating is guaranteed to confuse at least a few students.

One example for your Q is the Niemitzky plane (a.k.a. the Moore plane or Moore-Niemitzky plane).  See the definition in "Moore Plane" in Wikipedia. The countable set $\Bbb Q^2\cap (\Bbb R\times (0,\infty)\,)$ is dense. But the subspace $\Bbb R\times \{0\}$ is uncountable and discrete and hence not separable.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and examples. By the way, I see that you gone to U of Toronto.  Same here.  :)

Comment: You can find a lot about the topics & examples of the A's in General Topology by R. Engelking. It's a magnificent book.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{N}$ in your idea is a countable subspace so automatically separable. For all metric spaces, separability is hereditary, being equivalent to second countability, and also in ordered spaces separability is hereditary (but not equivalent to second countability). So examples will be a bit "wild", though it can happen in TVS's, e.g.:

As a better example: by a standard theorem $X=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ in the product topology is separable (e.g. the rational polynomials are countable and dense) and completely regular, but the subspace $A$ of all functions $\chi_x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (a function from $\Bbb R$ to itself that is $1$ for $x$, $0$ anywhere else for any fixed $x$) is uncountable and discrete so not separable.

A similar style example is the Sorgenfrey plane $\Bbb S^2$ (in Munkres $\Bbb R_l^2$) which has the antidiagonal $\{(x,-x): x \in \Bbb S\}$ as an uncountable discrete subspace and $\mathbb Q^2$ as a countable dense subset. Mrówka $\Psi$ and the Niemytzki plane, and the rational sequence topology are similar spaces. The phenomenon of separable spaces with large discrete subspaces is widespread.

Comment: You were correct in pointing out that my example was not a topological space, thank you for that correction

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sorry for my late response.  I just want to ask, for a given topological space, non separability is weird?  I mean it is weird like the cantor set kind of weirdness.

Comment: @SethMai no, I meant that a space that is separable but not all its subspaces separable is something you meet later in topology as the standard classes of metric and ordered spaces have no examples of this. But outside of those classes it’s quite common.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma the mathematical object: Uncountable discrete space sounds like an oxymoron.  When you have discrete objects, don't you associated it with countability?

Comment: @SethMai No. It’s just an uncountable set in the discrete topology. A set $A$ of a space$X$ is called discrete if for all $x \in A$ there is an open set $O$ such that $O \cap A =\{x\}$. No connection to countability at all.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ah ok I see. Thank you for the clarifications.